# SQL Server CE not picking up updates from another process?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce

I've got two processes with connections to the same SQL CE .sdf database file. One inserts items into a table and the other reads all the records from the table. After the insert I can confirm the rows are there with the Server Explorer but my query from the second process does not show them:

```
this.traceMessages.Clear();

SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT AppName, Message, TraceId FROM Messages", this.connection);

using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        this.traceMessages.Add(
            new TraceMessage
            {
                AppName = reader.GetString("AppName"),
                Message = reader.GetString("Message"),
                TraceId = reader.GetString("TraceId")
            });
    }
}
```

It can generally load up correctly the first time but doesn't pick up updates, even after restarting the process. The connection string just has a simple `Data Source` that I've confirmed is pointing to the same file on both processes.

Anyone know why this is happening? Is there some setting I can enable to get updates from separate processes to work?

Comment: Coudl you share/check 2 two connection string - do they have full paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because unlike "traditional" databases, the data that you write is not flushed to disk immediately, it is deferred and happens some time later.

You have two choices in the writing program:

1) Add the Flush Interval parameter to your connection string and set it to 1. This will have a lag of up to a second before the data is flushed to the sdf.

2) When you call Commit, use the parameterized overload that allows you to specify CommitMode.Immediate. This will flush data to disk immediately.

Comment: I wrapped the inserts in a transaction committed with CommitMode.Immediate, but it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: That is very strange. If server explorer can see them, but your app can't, then the only other thing I can think of is that the reading app is not reading the correct file. I know that you have checked this, but it probably wouldn't hurt to check one more time.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed a problem with pointing to the same file! The `|DataDirectory|\Traces.sdf` in the app config connection string was pointing to the .sdf in the bin folder while I was making updates to the one in the project folder. I was confused because the updates would make it through when I updated the value in the Server Explorer manually. I guess it was reading from the project file SDF and sometimes making updates to both?